# control dropbox in R without authentication every time?

Tags: r, dropbox

Hi I wanna using R to check dropbox and get the latest file. Now using `library(rdrop2)`

```
library(rdrop2)
# drop_auth() # username/password for 1st time
drop.file = drop_dir('daily_export')
which1 = grepl("^daily_export/hat.*.gz$", drop.file$path) # files begin with hat and end with .gz
drop.file = drop.file[which1, ]
drop.file = drop.file[ drop.file==max(drop.file$path), 'path']# max file name indicates latest
drop_get(drop.file$path) #download to current folder
```

It works but when I restart R, `drop_dir` needs my authentication - I need click agree in the browser.

I want to automate and schedule the R code. So I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid authentication every time. - Ways using other tools are welcomed too. Thanks!

Comment: It does not authenticate every time for me (just tried it again on OS X 10.11, R3.2.2). You may want to try explicitly setting `cache=TRUE` in `drop_auth()` the first time or see if any other oauth R packages you may use overwrite the dropbox settings.

Comment: hi @hrbrmstr i tried it and it worked! thank u very much!